# Sed replace string on alphanumeric with certain length that must contain one capitalized letter and one number

Tags: regex, sed, alphanumeric, positive-lookahead

I want to do a string replacement on any string that is surrounded by a word boundary that is alphanumeric and is 14 characters long.  The string must contain at least one capitalized letter and one number.  I know (I think I know) that I'll need to use positive look ahead for the capitalized letter and number.  I am sure that I have the right regex pattern.  What I don't understand is why `sed` is not matching.  I have used online tools to validate the pattern like regexpal etc.  Within those tools, I am matching the string like I expect.

Here is the regex and `sed` command I'm using.

`\b(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}\b`

The `sed` command I'm testing with is

`echo "asdfASDF1234ds" | sed 's/\b(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}\b/NEW_STRING/g'`

I would expect this to match on the echoed string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`sed` doesn't support lookaheads, or many many many other modern regex Perlisms. The simple fix is to use Perl.

```
perl -pe 's/\b(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}\b/NEW_STRING/g' <<< "asdfASDF1234ds"
```

Comment: I like this solution.  My problem is a little more complicated than I first stated.  I want to match on surrounding word boundaries, but not if there is a leading non-alphanumeric character immediately preceding it except for a colon.  I have not been able to find the right combination of look ahead and exceptions.  Any idea how I could do that as well?

Comment: The lookbehind `(?<![^\w:])` sounds like what you seem to be asking.

Comment: @tripleee this regex seems slightly broken. consider: `xx,a234567890123n,a23456789A1234o,a23456789A123n,yy`

Comment: I can't know what the OP's input looks like. I guess probably replace `.` with `\w` everywhere for better precision.

Comment: @tripleee yes, that seems to fix it. Basic issue is that the lookahead is not constrained to the 14 characters of interest. Needs somehow to be told to not search beyond the second `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` understands a [very limited form of regex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02). It does not have lookahead.

Using a tool with more powerful regex support is the simple solution.

If you must use `sed`, you could do something like:

```
$ sed '
    # mark delimiters
    s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,\}/\n&\n/g
    s/^[^\n]/\n&/
    s/[^\n]$/&\n/

    # mark 14-character candidates
    s/\n[a-zA-Z0-9]\{14\}\n/\n&\n/g

    # mark if candidate contains capital
    s/\n\n[^\n]*[A-Z][^\n]*\n\n/\n&\n/g

    # check for a digit; if found, replace
    s/\n\n\n[^\n]*[0-9][^\n]*\n\n\n/NEW_STRING/g

    # remove marks
    s/\n//g
' <<'EOD'
a234567890123n
,a234567890123n,
xx,a234567890123n,yy
a23456789A123n
XX,a23456789A123n,YY
xx,a23456789A1234n,yy
EOD
a234567890123n
,a234567890123n,
xx,a234567890123n,yy
NEW_STRING
XX,NEW_STRING,YY
xx,a23456789A1234n,yy
$
```

Comment: using `\n` in the replacement (rhs of `s///`) is not portable - instead use backslash followed by literal newline

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\<[A-Za-z0-9]{14}\>/\n&\n/
        s/\n.*(([A-Z].*[0-9])|([0-9].*[A-Z])).*\n/NEW_STRING/
        s/\n//g' file
```

Isolate a 14 alphanumeric word by delimiting it with newlines.

If the string between the newlines contains at least one uppercase alpha character and at least one numeric character, replace the string and its delimiters by `NEW_STRING`.

Remove the delimiters.

Or if multiple strings, perhaps:

```
sed -E 's/\b/\n/g
        s#.*#echo "&"|sed -E "/^[a-z0-9]{14}$/I{/[A-Z]/{/[0-9]/s/.*/NEW_STRING/}}"#e
        s/\n//g' file
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `.`. Maybe `[^\n]`. eg: `a,A234567890ABCD,,A234567890ABCD,`. Also need `s///g` everywhere

Comment: You definitely answered the question as stated.  I should rewrite it but the string may be preceded by a colon.  I only want to match if there is or isn't a colon but no other non-alnum chars.

Comment: @potong my suggestions don't actually fix the problem either. eg: `xx,a234567890123n,a23456789A1234o,a23456789A123n,yy`

Comment: @jhnc thankyou I've removed that ill thought out solution.